# Make children of QGraphicsItemGroup unselectable

Tags: python, pyqt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsitemgroup

In my app I am using the Graphics View framework and I am creating a lot of QGraphicsItemGroup. For example one group represents a text frame with some squares to resize the frame and another is a group of points representing a brush stroke. I am implementing a selection tool similar to the one you can find in Adobe Photoshop or Indesign. I implemented it as follow:

- In my scene I use the function itemAt(pos, transform) with pos being the current position of my mouse.
- Plus I called setFiltersChildEvents(True) in all the groups

However the item returned by itemAt is sometimes just a child of the group itself. Is there a way to make the function itemAt() returning the group of the item ? Or in another way, to make those children unselectable.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to get the group of the item

Below method available for `QGraphicsItem`, which returns `QGraphicsItemGroup`. Use this group object and set the desired.

```
PySide6.QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.group()
```

https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QGraphicsItem.html?highlight=qgraphicsitem#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.group